# Grub menu doesn't appear on HP Z220 Workstation

Tags: 12.04, grub2, dual-boot, windows-7, hp

I bought an analytical machine for some research purpose, the company provided
an HP Z220 Workstation with Windows 7 Professional preinstalled. I have tried to install Ubuntu 12.04 on this computer.

My problem is that no Grub menu appeared after the successful installation of Ubuntu. The machine is booting directly to Windows without showing any grub menu or anything on the screen.

I have tried:

- Reinstallation of Ubuntu
- Installation and updating of Grub using a live CD
- Mounting and unmounting of all partitions using a live CD
- Checked all options of Grub file using a live CD

Nothing worked. Can anyone tell me what could have gone wrong?

Comment: Provide out from: **`sudo update-grub`** (before you re-boot, to Windows 7). *We need to understand the partition structure, to understand what might be happening.*

Answer (score 0):

Boot-Repair is a little tool that solves most boot issues on Ubuntu.
Launch it from a live disk (CD or USB), and click the "`Recommended Repair`" button.
See https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair

[image]

(if any further issue after its use, indicate the URL it will provide)